# Mechanistic description of leverage

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

How would you describe how a lever is able to apply a large for to an object from only a small applied force *without* recourse to conservation of energy? Is there a purely F=ma type derivation? For example, how would you do it for a simple truss system (e.g., triangular truss with one end fixed to a pivot) and for an elastic beam over a fulcrum?

Comment: have a look at this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/lever.html

Comment: @annav thanks, but that referencec also appeals to conservation of energy. I would like to know HOW the force is actually multiplied. What are the internal forces doing to take a force of, say 1N and lever it up to 10N?

Comment: Is [torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) outside the realm of what you want?

Comment: please keep in mind that there is no conservation of force per se, only within limits of energy conservation.  It is multiplied by the larger distance multiplier.